# core data testing a migration mapping model

Tags: ios, core-data, ios4, core-data-migration

I was wondering what some people's opinions are about the best way to test a mapping model?  I'm currently working on an app to an upgrade of an app in the app store and want to test the mapping model hard before submitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been doing exactly this same thing.

I use iPhone Configuration Utility to install the 1.0 version of our app (repeatedly). After that, I simply run the current version of the app (1.0.1) in the debugger in Xcode. Works just fine. HTH

Comment: (the 1.0 version of the app is in the .ipa I used to submit to the App Store)

Comment: you think it's ok if i just use the codebase from the first version and install it on my phone and then install the new version, then check the db?

Comment: yeah..that would work too. delete the app, install 1.0, then build and run the new version. It's super convenient to have the 1.0 handy in iPhone Config Util though--you can reinstall quickly anytime while keeping the new version of your app in Xcode...

Comment: I'm not sure what the IPhone Config Util is, can you provide a link for it.

Comment: sure. it's for "enterprise" types. It lets you install/remove apps from a phone from your library (and other things). It's good for quickly installing an .ipa: http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/

Answer (score 3):

Found this one accidentally, to test a migration, before starting simulator, just... copy a file. You need to overwrite your app database with an older version *(all CoreData data and metadata is in)*

The Simulator install your app there :
`"/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOS Version>/Applications/<Some UUID>/"`

The CoreData Database is probably there (depends on what you do) :
`"/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOS Version>/Applications/<Some UUID>/Documents/whatever.sqlite3"`

You can quickly open this folder from terminal using :

```
open "`find ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/<iOS Version> -name '<your.app>'`/../Documents"`
```

Then just keep a backup before migration, and copy it over simulator one before starting your app.